# Aggregate bit column simulating AND operator

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, and-operator

I have some row I must aggregate, putting in AND a bit column. I let you see an example... I have a set of data like this:

```
Id   |  BitValue
----------------
1    |     1 
1    |     1
2    |     0
3    |     1
3    |     0
```

The result I hope to obtain is:

```
Id   |  BitValue
----------------
1    |     1 <- = (1 AND 1)
2    |     0
3    |     0 <- = (1 AND 0)
```

How can I aggregate the column to obtain the result I desire?

I have tried with theese 2 solutions, but no-one works:

```
SUM(CAST(MyBitField AS INT)),
SUM(CASE(MyBitField) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the `sum` with `count` if you have only 1 and 0 in that column:

```
select Id, case when sum(BitValue) < count(Id) then 0 else 1 end as BitValue 
from mytable group by Id;
```

[Sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6ae6/1).

Thanks for @Larnu's useful comment. I put up [another sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94c67/2) to reflect his concern.

Comment: As a quick note, if the OP's column `BitValue` is stored as a `bit`, then you'll need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value to a `tinyint` (or similar). You can't `SUM` a `bit` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
SELECT Id,
       Min(Cast(Bitvalue AS TINYINT)) * Max(Cast(Bitvalue AS TINYINT))
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY Id
```

or why not just `min` of Bitvalue

```
SELECT Id,
       Min(Cast(Bitvalue AS TINYINT))
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY Id
```

Both the method considers there is no NULL values in `BitValue` column

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 BitValue FROM TBL T1 WHERE T1.ID=T.ID AND 
    BitValue=0),1) AS  BitValue 
FROM TBL T
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/URJI50158)